# ServiceUnavailableError: Operation to settle the message has timed out as I try to read the messages in infinite loop

Tags: node.js, azure, queue, distributed-computing, azureservicebus

I want to continue to read the message from azure service bus queue. For this, I create message handlers inside a loop.

But while I am trying to do this, I get the following error sometimes:

```
    Error occurred:  { ServiceUnavailableError: Operation to settle the message has timed out. The disposition of the message may or may not be successful
    at Object.translate (/Users/reverie-pc/R/tests/service-bus/node_modules/@azure/amqp-common/dist/index.js:907:17)
    at Timeout.setTimeout [as _onTimeout] (/Users/reverie-pc/R/tests/service-bus/node_modules/@azure/service-bus/dist/index.js:2413:46)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
    at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)
    at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)
  name: 'ServiceUnavailableError',
  translated: true,
  retryable: true,
  info: undefined,
  condition: 'com.microsoft:timeout' }
```

I cannot understand the reason for this. Here is what I did:

```
const { ServiceBusClient, ReceiveMode, delay } = require("@azure/service-bus");

const connectionString = "Endpoint=sb://some-url";
const queueName = "my-queue";


async function main() {
  const sbClient = ServiceBusClient.createFromConnectionString(connectionString);

  const queueClient = sbClient.createQueueClient(queueName);

  const onMessageHandler = async (brokeredMessage) => {
    console.log(`Received message: ${brokeredMessage.body}`);
    await brokeredMessage.complete();
  };
  const onErrorHandler = (err) => {
    console.log("Error occurred: ", err);
  };


  try {
    for (; ;) {
      const receiver = queueClient.createReceiver(ReceiveMode.peekLock);
      receiver.registerMessageHandler(onMessageHandler, onErrorHandler, { autoComplete: false, maxConcurrentCalls: 10 });
      await delay(5000);
      await receiver.close();
    }
  } catch (err) {
    await queueClient.close();
  } finally {
    await queueClient.close();
    await sbClient.close();
  }
}

main().catch((err) => {
  console.log("Error occurred: ", err);
});
```

What could be the reason for this? Is this not the way to read messages?